# Restore Data on Hard Disk

Tags: restore

I formatted my HDD with the quick format. Can I restore my data? How?
I have not added nor written new data on it yet. I hope they are available somewhere on my HDD. The file system is Linux Filesystem.

Comment: Did you make any kind of backup before you formatted the HDD? If not, you'll have to reinstall everything from scratch... unless you mean to recover what was there before the format, then you can try `gparted` or `testdisk`. See http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: Quick answer: Yes, thankfully! See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/341376/file-recovery-after-quick-formatting

Comment: What do you mean by "the quick format" exactly?